# Android MediaFormat KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER ignored?

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediacodec

I am working on an app that streams the content of the screen and streams it over rtsp. I am using MediaCodec and VirtualDisplay. The problem I am having is that when the screen remains static, no data is sent over the network (new frames are not generated). After 10 seconds, clients disconnects. I have seen some posts in which people say they use KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER to fix this problem, but this values seems to be ignored.

This is the code that I am using:

```
MediaFormat format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE, VIDEO_WIDTH, VIDEO_HEIGHT);

format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT,
    MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_CAPTURE_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, 1); // 1 seconds between I-frames
format.setLong(MediaFormat.KEY_REPEAT_PREVIOUS_FRAME_AFTER, 1000000L / (long) FRAME_RATE);

MediaCodec mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(VIDEO_MIME_TYPE);
mediaCodec.configure(format, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
mediaCodecSurface = mediaCodec.createInputSurface();
mediaCodec.start();
```

FRAME_RATE is 30, VIDEO_MIME_TYPE is video/avc, BIT_RATE is 1800000, VIDEO_WIDTH is 1280 and VIDEO_HEIGHT is 720.

I pass mediaCodecSurface to VirtualDisplay.

Any suggestion?